# Print contents of array, when half way through insertion sort

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have written a simple insertion sort algorithm, it is working well. What I would like is if the program printed the contents of the array when it is half sorted. I can print the contents of the array just fine, but I cannot figure out how to tell when the array is half sorted. Here is my code

```
void insertion_sort(int *a, int n) {

    /*initialise data field*/
    int p;/*position index*/
    int key;/*key item*/
    int i;/*index in array*/

    /*for position in array*/
    for (p=1; p<n; p++){
        key = a[p];
        i= p-1;

        /*while i is valid and a[i] is less then key, move the item forward one*/
        while (i >= 0 && a[i] > key){
            a[i+1]=a[i];
            i--;
        }/*end while*/

        a[i+1]= key;
    }/*end for*/  
}/*end insertion_sort*/
```

Any help appreciated,
Cheers!

Comment: After `a[i+1]= key;`, if `p` is equal to `n / 2` (use some "floor" or "ceiling" function maybe?) your array should be half sorted.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "half sorted" ? Several interpretations are possible.

Answer (score 1):

After

```
a[i+1]= key;
```

if the position `p` is equal to half size of your array (`n/2`, if `n` is even or `n/2 + 1` otherwise - your call on what you define as half in that case), then your array will be half-sorted.